# Multiple conditions in a Perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

This is a pretty specific question regarding Perl regular expressions, I'm hoping it's not out of place.

I have a regex that matches one of several words:

`/foo|pizza|chicken/`

and one that matches 5 or more words:

`(?:\w+ ?){5,}`

I need to combine both of these into a single regex (an implementation limitation).  It this possible with a single regex?

- I like eating lots of pizza.  **should match**
- I like chicken on my pizza.  **should match**
- I need help with a regular expression.  **should not match**
- I like foo.  **should not match**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your second regex doesn't match 5 or more words, it matches one or more alphanumeric characters followed by an optional space, 5 times. That means that it matches `abcde`, which I'm guessing you don't want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use a [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to add a condition:

```
/^(?=.*\b(?:foo|pizza|chicken)\b)(?:\b\w+\b ?){5,}/
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/pQ6aG8/2).

I added [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to avoid mismatches on words like `food` or `pizzazz` and to make sure `\w+` always matches a whole word.

A slightly more efficient alternative uses [possessive quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) to ensure the same thing:

```
/^(?=.*\b(?:foo|pizza|chicken)\b)(?:\w++ ?){5,}/
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/pQ6aG8/1).

Comment: Your previous version was better.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: I was wondering what would be better - and I thought that word boundaries are more explicit and easier to understand, but I may have missed something...why did you prefer the version with possessive quantifiers?

Comment: I find it more straight-forward, shorter, more elegant. You should add it to your answer.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks @TimPietzcker!

Comment: Should probably be `\s*` there.